# How to ensure divs are staggered using appendChild

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do some `<div>` manipulations, removing some and adding others. I have a parent `<div>` with a number of `<div>`s in it:

```
<div id='parentdiv' style='width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto;'>
   <div id = 'div1' style='width:100%;height:400px;'>
      <canvas></canvas>
   </div>
   <div id='div2' style='width:100%;height:400px;'>
      <canvas></canvas>
   </div>
   <div id='div3' style='width:100%;height:400px;'>
      <canvas></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the `<div>`s are initially created they are all separated as expected, i.e. staggered underneith each other. If I however remove all of the initial `<div>`s like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("div" + c);
if (elem != null) {
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

and add them back in like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("parentdiv");
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.id = "div" + c;
d.style = "width:100%;height:400px;";
elem.appendChild(d);
```

The `<div>`s seem to stack on top of each other in the same space rather than  stagger. How do I make them stagger, am I missing a parameter?

Comment: What do you mean by stagger?

Comment: Please clarify "stagger" and post full code and also a https://jsfiddle.net/ fiddle would help

Comment: By stagger I mean the divs with content are shown separate under each other, as opposed to stacked like pancakes on top of each other

Comment: Your HTML has text nodes with whitespace between each DIV. When you append new children, you're not inserting any spaces between them. You should probably solve this with CSS, to specify the desired padding around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hopefully prevent others from doing the same mistake as I did, setting style of a div cannot be handled through a string, each individual attributes needs to be set like this

```
d.style.width = "100%";
d.style.height = "400px";
```

So the style settings were basically ignored, i.e. they took up no space.